# Target statement. What does it mean? - ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

What is the Target instance? I am a bit confused. Is it a 'Parameter'?

In this piece of code, what is the purpose of `event.target`? What does it do?

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER , hover);
function hover(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.alpha = .4;
    trace("Now over " + event.target.name);
}

addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT , normal);
function normal(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.apha = 1;
    trace("Now Off " + event.target.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The event target is the object where the event originated at. For the [event flow](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e4f.html), this is where the phase switches from capturing to bubbling.

So in case of mouse over/out events, this is where the mouse is actually hovering over/out. Due to the capturing/bubbling, this does not need to be the object you attached the event listener to (which is accessible via `currentTarget`).

---

In response to your comment:

`event` is just an object that holds some information about the particular event that has occurred (in your case a mouse over/out event), and is passed as an argument to the event hanlder, so it can query some information about the event.

Any object of type `Event` has a property `target` which is a *reference* to the object which *acts* as the target in this particular event instance. For mouse events, this is usually some visual object in the display list (for example another movieclip, a shape, or a button). Those [display objects](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html) have a property `alpha` which gets or sets their transparency value, making them transparent or opaque when displayed.

So when you chain all that, you get `event.target.alpha` which first gets the event instance, gets its target and then the alpha value of said target. Similarly, there is `event.target.name` which gets the name of the event target.

Comment: First of all , I would like to say : Thank you so much for taking the time to reply to this post! Means a lot to me 

So is the below right?

Event. - Its the Event that your defining

Target - What is it targeting though , is the target what your mouse is over?

Alpha - Is the transparency of that object

I appreciate your help!

Comment: @GeekAkash I have edited my question to hopefully answer those follow-up questions. Btw. if answers are helpful to you, you should [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) them.

Comment: yep Very Helpful! Thank you :D I don't have enough reputation as I'm new but I surely will soon! :)

Answer (score 0):

[`target`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#target) is a property of [`Event`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html)

In your handler function (the function you refer to when you `addEventListener`), you must accept one argument, which is an `Event`. When the handler function is called as a result of a relevant Event being dispatched, it is given a reference to that Event.

```
function hover(event:MouseEvent):void
// ------------^^^^^ This parameter refers to the dispatched Event.
```

Through that reference, you can access properties of the dispatched Event, one of which is `target` as I mentioned earlier.

> The event target. This property contains the target node. For example, if a user clicks an OK button, the target node is the display list node containing that button.

In most cases, it is usually more appropriate to use the [`currentTarget`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#currentTarget) property of the Event, which refers to the object that you added the event listener to.